# system() function string length limit

Tags: c, linux, posix

How long can be a string passed to `system()`?

I know the POSIX minimum is 4096, but I would like to know the actual size I can use.  Is there any macro defined in any header for that, similar to `FILENAME_MAX`?

```
char cmd[SOME_MACRO];

...
system(cmd);
```

Comment: Start worrying if your string is more than 100 KiB.  Until then, you should be OK.

Comment: If this is a problem for your programming, you are better off writing the command arguments into a file and updating the command to read that. Many programs, like the compiler and linker on Windows, can already read arguments from a file. Some Unix programs like `xargs` can read a stream of arguments and run one copy of the command template for each `n` arguments.

Comment: BTW, the `system()` function is a very different thing from a "system call" in the syscall (userspace/kernelspace boundary) sense of the word.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`system` exec's a shell with arguments `"sh","-c", YourAgumentToSystem, (char*)0` ([guaranteed by POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/system.html)), so
the maximum length (not counting the `'\0'` terminator) is `ARG_MAX -1 -3 -3 - size_of_your_environment`.

`ARG_MAX` is defined in [limits.h](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/limits.h.html) as

> "Maximum length of argument to the exec functions including
>   environment data."

If `limits.h`, doesn't define `ARG_MAX`, you [should be able to call](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/unistd.h.html)
`sysconf(_SC_ARG_MAX)` to obtain a runtime limit.

The linux manpage for [execve](https://linux.die.net/man/2/execve) (called by system) provides more information:

> On Linux prior to kernel 2.6.23, the memory used to store the
>   environment and argument strings was limited to 32 pages (defined by
>   the kernel constant MAX_ARG_PAGES). On architectures with a 4-kB page
>   size, this yields a maximum size of 128 kB.
>
> On kernel 2.6.23 and later, most architectures support a size limit
>   derived from the soft RLIMIT_STACK resource limit (see getrlimit(2))
>   that is in force at the time of the execve() call. (Architectures with
>   no memory management unit are excepted: they maintain the limit that
>   was in effect before kernel 2.6.23.) This change allows programs to
>   have a much larger argument and/or environment list. For these
>   architectures, the total size is limited to 1/4 of the allowed stack
>   size. (Imposing the 1/4-limit ensures that the new program always has
>   some stack space.) Since Linux 2.6.25, the kernel places a floor of 32
>   pages on this size limit, so that, even when RLIMIT_STACK is set very
>   low, applications are guaranteed to have at least as much argument and
>   environment space as was provided by Linux 2.6.23 and earlier. (This
>   guarantee was not provided in Linux 2.6.23 and 2.6.24.) Additionally,
>   the limit per string is 32 pages (the kernel constant MAX_ARG_STRLEN),
>   and the maximum number of strings is 0x7FFFFFFF.

To measure the size of your environment, you can run:

```
extern char **environ;
size_t envsz = 0; for(char **e=environ; *e; e++) envsz += strlen(*e)+1;
```

---

(As [Zan Lynx](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13422/zan-lynx) has pointed out in the comments, this can be sped up (cca 20 times as per my measurements—from 1600ns to 80ns for the 100-string 6KB environment I had when measuring)
 if you assume the `char*` pointers in `environ` point to a contiguous buffer, which they do after a program starts, but calls to `setenv`, `putenv`, or `unsetenv` typically break this:

```
extern char **environ;
char **e; for(e=environ; *e; e++) {}
size_t envsz =  ($_sz)(e[-1]+strlen(e[-1])+1 - *environ);
```

In any case, the speed up at the cost of robustness shouldn't matter much if you're expecting to fork+exec (/system) soon, given that fork+exec typically costs at least around 1-2ms on Linux on a modern machine.)

Comment: Note that this value may be large for allocation with automatic storage.

Comment: Its also not guarenteed that exceeding it will fail -- its (just) undefined behavior, so it may work one time you call it and fail the next.

Comment: I don't think that's the most efficient way to calculate environment size. I believe you can run the pointers up until the NULL and subtract from environ, without involving `strlen` calls.

Comment: @ZanLynx I think that'll only work with a fresh environment. The environment-manipulating functions don't appear to keep the backend contiguous.

Comment: @PSkocik Ah yeah, that looks to be true. Hmm.

Comment: @ZanLynx Tried it. Your method is 20× faster than mine (80ns vs 1600ns on my env of 100 values / 6K bytes together), but `setenv`/`putenv` and `unsetenv` break it. In any case, if you're about to fork/exec that's about to cost like 2ms. Even the 1600ns is less than 1 millionth of that.

Answer (score 4):

The limit is highly system dependent. It may even depend on the command shell that will be used. You should test the return value of `system()` to see if the system call was successful: `-1` means failure and `errno` should give you more information. The behavior should be defined for any proper C string.

[POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/system.html) documents that `system(command)` is equivalent to:

```
execl(<shell path>, "sh", "-c", command, (char *)0);
```

And also documents `ARG_MAX` defined in `<limits.h>` as the limit for the combined lengths of the arguments to `exec` and the environment variables.

Note however that `command` may contain wildcards and/or other shell words whose expansion may exceed some other limit. Always check the return value for failure.

Answer (score 3):

> man 3 system

gives us

> DESCRIPTION
>
> The  system()  library function uses fork(2) to create a child process that executes the shell command specified in command
>          using execl(3) as follows:
>
> ```
>        execl("/bin/sh", "sh", "-c", command, (char *) 0);
>
>    system() returns after the command has been completed.
> ```
>
> so system() is a wrapper for `execl()`

From the same page we also see that this call conforms to some standards.

> CONFORMING TO
>
> POSIX.1-2001, POSIX.1-2008, C89, C99.

Looking up **POSIX.1-2008** produces the following online reference

https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/

Where we can search for info on the `execl` function which system takes us to

https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/exec.html

Which offers up the following

> The number of bytes available for the new process' combined argument and environment lists is {ARG_MAX}. It is implementation-defined whether null terminators, pointers, and/or any alignment bytes are included in this total.

And finally ...

> ERRORS
>
> The exec functions shall fail if:
>
> [E2BIG] The number of bytes used by the new process image's argument
>   list and environment list is greater than the system-imposed limit of
>   {ARG_MAX} bytes.

So the final check to carry out here is the actual exec implementation rather than relying on the standard just in case the implementation deviated from the standard.

So, `man 3 execl` reports that the errors returned are the same as documented for `execve(2)` and `man 2 execvw` reports the following:

> ERRORS
>
> E2BIG  The total number of bytes in the environment (envp) and argument list (argv) is too large.

Not as precise as the POSIX standard? Best check the code or see the (now) accepted answer :)